# Crashed: Thread libffmpeg.so (Missing)

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, crashlytics, vitamio

there are many crashes on fabric console with below log

```
 Crashed: Thread
    0  libffmpeg.so                   0x6be6c5de (Missing)
    1  libffmpeg.so                   0x6bfc51fa (Missing)
    2  libffmpeg.so                   0x6bfab616 (Missing)
    3  libffmpeg.so                   0x6bfd28ba (Missing)
    4  libffmpeg.so                   0x6becfbbf (Missing)
    5  libffmpeg.so                   0x6bfc5c26 (Missing)
    6  libffmpeg.so                   0x6bfd287e (Missing)
    7  libffmpeg.so                   0x6bfd28ba (Missing)
    8  libffmpeg.so                   0x6bfab616 (Missing)
    9  libffmpeg.so                   0x6bfd2912 (Missing)
    10 libffmpeg.so                   0x6bfd28fe (Missing)
    11 libffmpeg.so                   0x6bed0b55 (Missing)
    12 libffmpeg.so                   0x6bfd29f6 (Missing)
    13 libffmpeg.so                   0x6bdfb8c3 (Missing)
    14 libffmpeg.so                   0x6bfa6e4a (Missing)
    15 libc.so                        0x40094784 (Missing)
    16 libutils.so                    0x400fe9ca (Missing)
    17 libGLES_mali.so                0x5b9cd052 (Missing)
    18 libGLES_mali.so                0x5b9cd622 (Missing)
    19 libGLES_mali.so                0x5b9d7cae (Missing)
    20 libGLES_mali.so                0x5b9d7d26 (Missing)
    21 libGLES_mali.so                0x5b9cc6b6 (Missing)
    22 libGLES_mali.so                0x5b9d7cae (Missing)
    23 libEGL.so                      0x402e849b (Missing)
    24 libEGL.so                      0x402ea077 (Missing)
    25 libc.so                        0x400b00f6 (Missing)
    26 libutils.so                    0x400fc94f (Missing)
    27 libandroid_runtime.so          0x401a878f (Missing)
    28 (Missing)                      0x57556056 (Missing)
    29 libdvm.so                      0x414ba38e (Missing)
    30 (Missing)                      0x417c1f76 (Missing)
    31 libdvm.so                      0x414ea7b5 (Missing)
    32 (Missing)                      0x591f4816 (Missing)
    33 libandroid_runtime.so          0x401a87a9 (Missing)
    34 libc.so                        0x40083f2b (Missing)
    35 libdvm.so                      0x4151621b (Missing)
    36 (Missing)                      0x5752c916 (Missing)
    37 (Missing)                      0x428b97ce (Missing)
    38 libdvm.so                      0x4150feaf (Missing)
    39 libdvm.so                      0x415096e3 (Missing)
    40 (Missing)                      0x41df9bbe (Missing)
    41 (Missing)                      0x417c8b26 (Missing)
    42 (Missing)                      0x427956e6 (Missing)
    43 (Missing)                      0x41e1e442 (Missing)
    44 (Missing)                      0x41e1e43e (Missing)
    45 libdvm.so                      0x414ef75f (Missing)
    46 libdvm.so                      0x414ef677 (Missing)
    47 (Missing)                      0x58f7244c (Missing)
    48 libdvm.so                      0x414ea623 (Missing)
    49 (Missing)                      0x655e5216 (Missing)
    50 (Missing)                      0x575d3a4e (Missing)
    51 (Missing)                      0x41e1aee2 (Missing)
    52 libdvm.so                      0x414ca6ae (Missing)
    53 (Missing)                      0x41e0ea96 (Missing)
    54 libdvm.so                      0x414ca65e (Missing)
    55 (Missing)                      0x575d3a4e (Missing)
    56 libdvm.so                      0x414c7d5a (Missing)
    57 (Missing)                      0x59670cde (Missing)
    58 (Missing)                      0x574fc61e (Missing)
    59 (Missing)                      0x58808ffe (Missing)
    60 (Missing)                      0x41e1ae4e (Missing)
    61 (Missing)                      0x575d3a4e (Missing)
    62 (Missing)                      0x4179a2a6 (Missing)
    63 (Missing)                      0x41e1ae0a (Missing)
    64 libdvm.so                      0x414fd1cf (Missing)
```

My application has a streaming for a Live Video and Audio, I have used [vitamio](https://www.vitamio.org/en/) SDK for that. I am not able to track the issue, is there why using I can identify the issue.

I have tested on many devices, but get failed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Do you have access to a debug version of the libraries you're using for NDK code?

Comment: @MikeBonnell No i don't have the access for that

Comment: Gotcha, in that case, there's no way for us to get the symbols for that library so the stack trace will have missing symbols.

Comment: @MikeBonnell sorry, there is a mistake from my side, Yes I am able to debug a vitamio that using a NDK code

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. If you have other libraries for your NDK code, then you need to upload symbols for them. [Depending](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/ndk.html#uploading-symbols-for-external-dependencies) on which version of Fabric's Gradle plugin and Gradle you're running, here is a way to upload them.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
  compileSdkVersion <CURRENT COMPILESDKVERSION>
  buildToolsVersion "<YOUR BUILD TOOLS VERSION>"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "<YOUR APP'S PACKAGE NAME>"
  }
}

crashlytics {
  enableNdk true
  // If using the Android plugin for Gradle version 2.2.0+ with the externalNativeBuild DSL,
  // you should remove the androidNdkOut and androidNdkLibsOut properties, as these paths will
  // automatically be detected by the Fabric plugin.
  androidNdkOut 'obj'
  androidNdkLibsOut 'libs'
  manifestPath 'AndroidManifest.xml'
}
```

Finally run `./gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease` to upload your symbols. You need to do this for any build you need crashes for and if you're using older versions where `androidNdkOut` and `androidNdkLibsOut`is needed. Libs is for release and non-libs is for debug.